# VB.Net Get Property Value by Name

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable

I am trying to create a constructor that loads Data into Properties from a database.
I already have working functions that pull the table data and the table column names.
I am trying to figure out how to get and set data to the properties.
Everything works until I get to the getValue and setValue functions.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

```
Sub New(ID As Integer)
        Dim strTable As String = "Ration"
        Dim strField As String = "RationID"
        Dim queryString As String = "Select * From " & strTable & " Where " & strField & " = '" & ID & "';"
        Console.WriteLine("SQL: " & queryString)
        Dim dtDataTable As DataTable = DataManager.RunQueryForDataTable(queryString)
        Dim dtColumns As DataTable = DataManager.getColumnNames(strTable)
        For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
            For Each col As DataRow In dtColumns.Rows
                Dim pinfo As PropertyInfo = Me.GetType().GetProperty(col("Column Name"))
                Console.WriteLine("Column: " & col("Column Name").ToString)
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " & pinfo.Name)
                Console.WriteLine("Type: " & pinfo.PropertyType.ToString)
                Console.WriteLine("Value: " & pinfo.GetValue(Me, New Object() {0}))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use parameters, trust me...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Parameters"?

Comment: Well I could, but it's been around for a long time, check this link: **http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?548787-Database-Why-should-I-use-Parameters-instead-of-putting-values-into-my-SQL-string**

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that doesn't solve the issue of setting Class Properties Dynamically.

Comment: I know it doesn't I was just saying that's something to look into :)

Comment: Roger Wilco Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem

```
Console.WriteLine("Value: " & pinfo.GetValue(Me, New Object() {0}))
```

Needs to be

```
Console.WriteLine("Value: " & pinfo.GetValue(Me, Nothing))
```